# Map is not being loaded in an Android Kotlin App

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I have dependencies as:

```
// Google Maps Location Services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'

// KTX for the Maps SDK for Android
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-ktx:3.4.0'

// (Optional) KTX for the Maps SDK for Android Utility Library
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:maps-utils-ktx:3.4.0'
```

Manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".RunTrackerApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RunTracker"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Fragment XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.tracking.TrackingFragment">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/tracking_map_view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clInnerLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

with all given above when I configure Map in Fragment as:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class TrackingFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private var _binding: FragmentTrackingBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val trackingViewModel: TrackingViewModel by viewModels()

    // Init Map
    private lateinit var mapView: GoogleMap

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentTrackingBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        return root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            mapView = binding.mapView.awaitMap()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        if (isServiceOK()){
            googleMap.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))
                    .title("Marker")
            )
        }
    }

    private fun isServiceOK(): Boolean {
        val result =  GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(requireContext())

        if (result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true
        } else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(result)){
            val dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
                .getErrorDialog(this, ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING, 1012)

            dialog?.show()
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

I have followed all the guidelines and Enabled Maps SDK for Android:

[image: Maps SDK for Android]

but Map is never shown:

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: It looks to like there was a problem in your implementation of the API Key, can you try to double check that? If it still did not work, can you push a working code in your github repo that demonstrates this issue that we can clone and test in our end?

Comment: I agree, you need to check `android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}"` as it seems you forgot it replace the API key. You can compile the app, unzip it, and look at the Manifest in the app. If it does not have an API key then this is most likely a problem

Comment: I have not forgotten API_KEY value, I have followed guides from  [Step 3 Add Your Api key to the project](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#step_3_add_your_api_key_to_the_project)

Comment: So you were able to put it inside the `local.properties`?

Comment: Yes everything from my side is well configured 